# Create page to view through facebook app

Tags: php, facebook

I have created a facebook app i want my index.php file to be seen only through facebook app page and not to be seen by typing direct url of my domain .Right now the page is seen from both ends.

For eg:- if go to ***http://apps.facebook.com/myAppname/***  i should see the content of my index.php but if i go through "***http://mydomain/***" it should be a blank page or should say not allowed . how do i implement the logical filters for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP to accomplish this:

```
<?
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match("http://apps.facebook.com/myAppname/",$referrer)) {
      header('Location: http://www.mydomain/index.php');
} else {
      header('Location: http://www.mydomain/blank.php');
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'facebook.com'){
// Serve page
} else {
// Serve blank
}
```